# Kotlin Async API definition with Generics

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I moving my framework written in Java Android to Kotlin, to be able to support crossplatform trend.
I'm pretty much new to Kotlin and I can't figure out all the details all the way.

The issue that I have is to rewrite existing Java interface to Kotlin, and to be able to include in/out varaince to be able to easily pass different generic subclasses.

Existing Java API is this:

```
/**
 * Channels API
 *
 * @author Veljko Ilkic
 */
public interface ChannelsAPI<T extends TvChannel, C extends EntityCategory> {

    /**
     * Get channel list
     *
     * @param callback
     */
    void getChannelList(AsyncDataReceiver<ArrayList<T>> callback);
```

Phase one moving to Kotlin is this:

```
/**
 * Channels API
 *
 * @author Veljko Ilkic
 */
interface ChannelsInAPI<T : TvChannel<*>?, C : EntityCategory?> {

    /**
     * Get channel list
     *
     * @param callback
     */
    fun getChannelList(callback: AsyncDataReceiver<List<T>?>?)
```

Now what I want to avoid explictly defining all generic types in my client application that uses this framework. What my understanding is that when I use in/out generics, complier can figure out itself generic types at runtime like in Java.

Currently I' facing this issue:

```
/**
 * Channels API
 *
 * @author Veljko Ilkic
 */
interface ChannelsOutAPI<in T : TvChannel<*>?, C : EntityCategory?> {

    /**
     * Get channel list
     *
     * @param callback
     */
    fun getChannelList(callback: AsyncDataReceiver<List<T>?>?)
```

**Type parameter T is declared as 'in' but occurs in 'invariant' position in type AsyncDataReceiver<List?>?**

I'm not sure if I explained the problem the right way.
But idea is to split my existing APIs into smaller segments with in and out parameters and be able to reduce explict type definiton.

All of my APIs are async calls, and returs data via this callback class which also accepts generics.

```
/**
 * Async receiver interface
 *
 *
 * Used for async events callback
 *
 * @author Veljko Ilkic
 */
interface AsyncDataReceiver<T> {

    /**
     * On data receive success
     */
    fun onReceive(data: T)

    /**
     * On data receive failed
     *
     * @param error error
     */
    fun onFailed(error: Error?)
}
```

UPDATE:

```
/**
 * Async receiver interface
 *
 *
 * Used for async events callback
 *
 * @author Veljko Ilkic
 */
interface AsyncDataReceiver<**in** T> {

    /**
     * On data receive success
     */
    fun onReceive(data: T)

    /**
     * On data receive failed
     *
     * @param error error
     */
    fun onFailed(error: Error?)
}
```

This fixes the error, but from logic point of view, AsyncDataReceiver should have OUT parameter, but it uses it as IN parameter.

Comment: You're getting the error because by defining a type as `in` or invariant, you're explicitly stating that that class will only consume types of T, but you're returning (or producing) a list of type T which breaks that rule

Comment: I understand the error, but can not figure out workaround, to have similar behaviour as I had in Java.

In AsyncDataReceiver I've state T as IN parameter, which fixes the error.
But there is logical missleaning in that case, AsyncDataReceiver basically produces T generic, but it's labeled as IN.

Comment: Do you have to label it as `in`? can it just be the generic?

Comment: Currently it's just generic and it works fine.
The issue is that the code became really ugly, because I have few levels of generic abstraction. In that case API user, needs to define the whole stack of generic types.

I have abstract TvChannel, which accepts few also generic types, which also accepts few generic types.

Client app because really messy, because of Kotlin forcing me to specify each generic type in hierarchy.

My understading is that in/out helps of avoidin that problem, and that I can pass supertype as generic and viceversea. Correct?

Comment: AsyncDataDetriever is a T consumer, so it should logically be `in` There isn’t a direct equivalent to Java’s raw types, but raw types aren’t safe anyway. You can do the same thing using star projection and casting as needed.